# 'set to a higher value' or 'set as a higher value'?

Tags: word-usage

Someone told me that it is incorrect to say
"Set the threshold to a higher value". 
Instead, it should be "Set the threshold as a higher value"
because if a specific number does not come after "set", like "Set the threshold to 0", it sounds awkward. Is he right?

Comment: Have you tried googling "to a higher value" and "as a higher value"?

Comment: *Set to* is idiomatic for making a measuring device take on a particular value. *Set as* is rarely used, and it means something different, namely to make on thing take on the characteristics of another: *set gold as  a common currency*.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the difference, orally or grammatically, between "Set the threshold to [a specific value]" and "Set the threshold to a higher value? For example, "Set the the threshold to 3.14159265358979 volts" versus "Set the threshold to a higher voltage".

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to your impression the usage of *set to number* is much more idiomatic than *set as number*. Have a look at [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+to+*_NUM%2C+set+as+*_NUM&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cset%20to%20%2A_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bset%20to%20zero_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20to%201_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20to%20one_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20to%200_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20to%202_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20to%2010_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20to%20100_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20to%203_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20to%205_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20to%204_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cset%20as%20%2A_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bset%20as%20one_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20as%20100_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20as%20two_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20as%201_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20as%20zero_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20as%200_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20as%20three_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20as%202_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20as%2010_NUM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bset%20as%203_NUM%3B%2Cc0).

[image: Makes me bigger!]

All the popular versions of *set as* are dwarfed by the *set to* usages.

Comment: How about *set at*?

Comment: Absolutely not. The two are not truly comparable.

'Set the threshold as a higher value" because if a specific number does not come after "set", like "Set the threshold to 0", it sounds awkward. Is he right?

Comment: Absolutely not. The two are not really comparable.

'Set the threshold  a higher value" implies that whatever the vallue, the threshold should be changed for the purpose of future comparison with other values. The point is the process of comparison, not the value itself.

'Set the threshold  ' 0 or anything else, makes the point the specific value, rahter than the process.